# Time Series Chart breakdown fails when datasource is blended data

Tags: looker-studio

Time series chart is failing when datasource is blended data, breakd down dimension is being duplicated.
Actually it is strange first was showing to many rows then I deleted chart and added again now is showing this(as image presents). Dimension is date type(Day of Month), breakdown is date type(Year Month)
[Image that shows chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQZ4u.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to show the day of the month (1st to 31th) on the x-axis? For each month a new line should be displayed?

Since the x-axis is a value from 1 to 31, a line-chart is needed.

In the original datset or during blending add the two following calculated fields to dimensions:

```
EXTRACT(day from dates)
```

```
DATETIME_TRUNC(dates,month)
```

The first one will be the x-axis of the line-chart, the 2nd one the break-down-dimension.

Comment: I have achieved my goal and it was working fine, but then in attempt to authorize data for row, I blended data with a datasource that contains data for authorizations, but once I did that the chart its failing, chart has same configuration that it had before blending the data.

Comment: @en123 I guess the blending could lead to duplicated datapoints. Could you blend a dummy authorize dataset with only one e-mail?

Comment: Actually I did that, I blended with a dataset that had only one email!